# MATLAB: intersections of two conics

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to create Voronoi diagram for circles. In that case the voronoi edge is branch of hyperbola or line (special case).
So, my goal is to find all possible intersections of two conics (especially hyperbolas) given by implicit function **f_i(x,y)=0**.

Next steps are to decide which points are Voronoi points and [draw "line" between them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484646/matlab-plotting-conic-betwwen-two-points).

Thanks for any approach, I'm going quite desperate about it...

Comment: I have a hard time understanding your question. Can you upload a sketch of what you're trying to do, please?

Answer (score 1):

Start here:
http://people.eecs.ku.edu/~miller/Papers/DetectAndCalc.pdf