# MATLAB: plotting conic between two points

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to create Voronoi diagrams for circles where edges are parts of hyperbola or line (special case)

My goal is to plot section of given conic between two given points.

The conic is defined by implicit function **f(x,y)=0** and points are defined [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484453/matlab-intersections-of-two-conics)

I appreciate any kind of approach, I've run out of ideas...